# How to Initiate Call from Raspberry Pi on Android Device

Tags: android, ssh, raspberry-pi, usb

So lets say I am connected to a Raspberry Pi via SSH on my local network. 
Now i want to initiate a call from an Android device which is connected to the Raspberry Pi via USB using either the Command Line in Terminal or Mirror the Androids Screen and dial the number "by hand". 
[LayOut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jipiu.png)

Does someone have any idea how i can realise that ?

I Have found a lot of information on how to control an Raspberry Pi using an Android phone but sadly not the oher way arround.

p.s.: I dont need to hear or speak to the other phone. I just want to fetch the network data with wireshark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ssh` to get a shell on the android ( https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/118738/how-to-ssh-into-an-unrooted-android-device-using-sshdroid-from-a-linux-computer )

calls are managed on android by the `phone service` that is an android system service ( https://anatomyofandroid.com/2013/10/03/system-services/, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html )

if you have the shell ( and if you have **root** ) you can invoke calls like

```
# service call phone 2 s16 "+1234567890"
service call phone 2 s16 "+1234567890"
Result: Parcel(NULL)
```

source : https://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/12/android-calldial-from-the-adb-shell-command-line/
i

for mirroring the android screen you can use a VNC server on the android and a VNC client on the Rpi

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find a way to communicate with the Android device over USB.

1. SSH (http://sumoudou.org/How%20to%20ssh%20into%20an%20Android%20phone%20over%20USB.html)
2. Serial over USB.

then to communicate 'data' over a call you will have to figure a way to encode/decode data over a voice channel.(i.e. DTMF, etc) or you can always opt to communicate over IP.

At the end Whatever this mediator app/daemon running inside your android device will relay the data to the USB (SSH,usb serial, etc).